# I'm getting this error while running the following code on sql developer ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE
    v_start_date INT := 20220302;
    objtosearch varchar2(50) := '%data%';
BEGIN
    WHILE v_start_date <= 20230331 LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ( '
    insert into bazey.data_usage
        SELECT
            ft.id_date,
            vs.nr_orgn,
            SUM(qt_upld_trfc + qt_dwld_trfc) usage_mbs
        FROM
                 (
                SELECT
                    *
                FROM
                    fct_trf
                WHERE
                        ft.id_date = '
                            || v_start_date
                            || '
                    AND x_file_name =: objtosearch
            ) ft
            JOIN voice_data_sample vs ON substr(ft.nr_orgn, - 9, 9) = vs.nr_orgn
        GROUP BY
            ft.id_date,
            vs.nr_orgn
    ' );
        COMMIT;
        v_start_date := to_number(to_char(to_date(v_start_date, 'YYYYMMDD') + 1, 'YYYYMMDD'));

    END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 AND x_file_name =: objtosearch
```

here you have a `:` bind variable marker, though you should remove the space between that and the name. When you have binds inside `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`, to actually bind it you have to specify the variable using the `USING` clause. It won't match automatically simply because the name is the same. And if you do this for objtosearch, you really should do the same to start_date:

```
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '
    insert into bazey.data_usage
        SELECT
            ft.id_date,
            vs.nr_orgn,
            SUM(qt_upld_trfc + qt_dwld_trfc) usage_mbs
        FROM
                 (
                SELECT
                    *
                FROM
                    fct_trf
                WHERE   ft.id_date = :start_date
                    AND x_file_name =:objtosearch
            ) ft
            JOIN voice_data_sample vs ON substr(ft.nr_orgn, - 9, 9) = vs.nr_orgn
        GROUP BY
            ft.id_date,
            vs.nr_orgn
    ' USING var_start_date,objtosearch;
```

If I may suggest, however, you really have no reason at all use to `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` at all here. We use dynamic SQL only if the object names (column names, table names) or large structural items (join clauses, query blocks, etc.) need to be programmatically set and can change. If all that's changing is data values you are looking for, don't use dynamic SQL, use normal SQL:

```
  insert into bazey.data_usage
            SELECT
                ft.id_date,
                vs.nr_orgn,
                SUM(qt_upld_trfc + qt_dwld_trfc) usage_mbs
            FROM
                     (
                    SELECT
                        *
                    FROM
                        fct_trf
                    WHERE
                            ft.id_date = v_start_date
                        AND x_file_name = objtosearch
                ) ft
                JOIN voice_data_sample vs ON substr(ft.nr_orgn, - 9, 9) = vs.nr_orgn
            GROUP BY
                ft.id_date,
                vs.nr_orgn;
```